# Period of $\sin(ax)+\cos(bx)$

Tags: periodic-functions

Take the function $f(x)=\sin(ax)\cos(bx)$, with $a,b>0$. Suppose there are positive integer $p$ and $q$ such that $ap=bq=r$.

Then $r$ is a period of $f$ but non always the shortest :  for $f(x)= \sin x\cdot  \cos(3x)$ the shortest period isn't $2\pi$, but $pi$.

If    $f(x)= \sin(ax)+\cos(bx)$, $r$ should always be the fundamental period of $f$ ?  And if so, how to prove it?

Comment: You're title says $\sin(ax)+\cos(bx)$, but your question says $\sin(ax)\cos(bx)$.

Comment: Don't you mean something like $\frac{2\pi}{a} p + \frac{2\pi}{b} q = r$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - The question begins with assertions about $\sin(ax)\cos(bx)$, but concludes with a question about $\sin(ax)+\cos(bx)$.