# period of the sum and the product of $\sin(ax)$ and $\cos(bx)$

Tags: periodic-functions

Take the function f(x)=sin(ax)cos(bx) , with a,b>0 . We know that the fundamental period of sin(ax) is  p= 2π/a and the fundamental period of cos(bx) is q=2π/b.  Suppose there are positive integer n  and m  such that np=mq=r, with n/m reduced to its lowest term; then r  is a period of f(x)  but not always the shortest : for f(x)=sinx⋅cos(3x)  we have r = 2π , but  the fundamental period is π. Now, consider the sum instead of the product of sin(ax) and cos(bx).If g(x)=sin(ax)+cos(bx) , r  should always be the fundamental period of  g(x) ? And if so, how to prove it?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions?rq=1) may be helpful. Also see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127154/what-is-the-periodicity-of-the-function-sinax-cosbx-where-a-and-b-ar?rq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056801/period-of-sinax-cosbx?rq=1).